# Dead space after enumerate in tabularx

Tags: tables, spacing, lists, tabularx, enumitem

I am trying to display a list in a table using `tabularx` and make the margins/paddings really tight using `enumitem`.

```latex
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
    \setlist{nosep,leftmargin=1em}

\begin{document}
This is a long test sentence
    \begin{itemize}
        \item foo
        \item bar
    \end{itemize}
continuing here.

\vspace{2cm}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{rX}
    foo & bar
    \begin{itemize}
        \item test
        \item foobar
    \end{itemize}
    \\
    baz & barfoo \\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image: result]

While margin reset works perfectly outside table as seen in the first example, once it is inside the table as in the second example, a blank line is inserted after the list. How do I get rid of it?

(I'm using `KOMAScript` and `LuaLaTeX` btw)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every list has defined `topsep`, `\parskip` and `\partopsep`  vertical space above and below list.  This spaces <ou can remove on two ways:

- use `enumitem` parameters `before` and `after` (first example)
- encapsulate list in `minipage` (second example)

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
    \setlist{nosep,leftmargin=1em}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{rX}
    foo & bar
    \begin{itemize}[after=\vspace{-\baselineskip}]
        \item test
        \item foobar
    \end{itemize}
    \\
    baz & barfoo \\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A bit more sophisticated solution with defining new list, let named it `\tabitem`, which encapsulate list in `minipage`:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{tabitem}{itemize}{1}   % <-- defined new list
\setlist[tabitem]{nosep=0pt,
                 leftmargin=*,
                 label=\textbullet,
                 after=\end{minipage},                  % <---
                 before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\raggedright % <---
                 }
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{rX}
    foo & bar
    
    \begin{tabitem}
        \item \lipsum[66]
        \item foobar
    \end{tabitem}   \\
    baz & \begin{tabitem}
        \item \lipsum[66]
        \item foobar
    \end{tabitem}   \\
text    & \lipsum[66]
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: congratulations on 200k to @Zarko

Comment: @jsbibra, not jet :-). Exactly number is 199 557. I expect once at end of week. Thank you very much for congratulation!

Comment: My congratulations too! (+1)

Comment: @Bernard, thank you very much!

Comment: okay well, that seemed a bit hacky, but it works, thanks!

Comment: @PhilippStephan, it is quite standard solution. See edited answer.